# How to copy a line from input text

Tags: c, text, input, copy, line

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *ptr_file, *wr_file;
    int count = 0, i, count2 = 0, j, count3 = 0;
    char string[200];
    char text[200];

    ptr_file =fopen("input.txt","r");
    if (!ptr_file)
        return 1;
    while (fgets(string,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL)
    {
        while (string[count] != '>')
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= count; i++)
    {
        text[i] = string[i];    
    }

    while (string[count2] != ')') //I cant put '\n' in here as end of line, so I use ')' instead
    {
        count2++;
    }

    for (j = count; j <= count2; j++)
    {
        text[j] = string[j];
    }

    printf("text: %s\n", text); 
    return(0);  
}
```

This code is a part of a program that Ive been working on, I just cropped the problematic ones. Hence the 2 counts (count and count2).

So, the code was supposed to read the input.txt and then print the first line.

The input.txt contains this:

```
1. 1-KU1071=B 2-KI1201=B 57 ==> 3-FI1101=B 56    conf:(0.98)
carrotcake
eggjuice
```

When I ran the code, the result is:

```
eggjuice
```

Why did it print the last line of the text? How can I fix so that it would only print the first line.

Ive even tried using strncopy

```
 strncpy(text, &string[0], j);
```

But still the same result.

PS: theres a reason of why I divide the string into 2 parts, before '>' and after '>'. So, I cant change that.

Comment: `fgets(string, 1000, ptr_file)` must be `fgets(string, 200, ptr_file)` or better yet: `fgets(string, sizeof string, ptr_file)`

Comment: The first loop of your code is `while (fgets(string,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL)
while (string[count] != '>')
{
    count++;
}` -- the rest does not belong to `while(fgets())` loop. Is that what you intended? Add missing curly braces if not.

Comment: You input a string allowing 1000 characters, but you provide a buffer 200 char long - if the line happens to exceed 200 bytes, the input data will overflow the buffer and overwrite some, possibly vital, data in memory, which will crash your program.

Comment: In the inner `while` you increment `count` until a '>' character is found in `string` at counted position. Have you considered what happens if there's no such character is the string...?

Comment: Two remarks. You have written to `text[count]` twice, once at the end of the `for (i...)` loop, again at the start of the `for (j...)` loop. Also, as local variable, `text[]` is undefined, but you have not placed a string terminator. If `text[]` was a static variable, it would be initialised to 0's but it's sloppy to assume that, especially if the second time you use it, it gets a shorter string than the first time. So you need to add `text[j] = 0;` after the loop.